# Opening view in a new tab on click of Sitemap Node in MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

**How do I Open a View in a New tab on click of Sitemap Node to which it is mapped.**
for example:

How do I open 'Index' View in New tab on click of Reports item?

```
> SiteMapNode title="Reports" controller="Reports" action="Index"
```

Right now its opening in the same Window. I tried using target = "_blank" but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hurray!

I solved it by passing URL parameter to sitemapnode.

< siteMapNode title="Reports" url="javascript:var w=window.open('/Reports/Index','');" >